# Why typedef doesn't work with pthread?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm trying to send a typedef through a function. However, it seems I can't.

```
#define MAX 2
typedef struct
{
    unsigned long myPid;
    unsigned long parentPid;
    unsigned long myTid;
} myProperties;

void* funcproperties(void* arg);
void createthread(myProperties (*properties)[MAX]);
```

So this is how my typedef is defined.

```
void* funcproperties(void* arg)
{
    myProperties *properties=(myProperties*) arg;   
    properties->myPid=getpid();
    properties->parentPid=getppid();    
    properties->myTid=syscall(SYS_gettid);
    return NULL;
}
```

**If I give values to `properties[0].myPid=getpid()`, I won't have problems. However, when I send the address of the position where the typedef will start (0 or 1), it doesn't.  I wonder why? Maybe pthread doesn't support it?**

```
void createthread(myProperties (*properties)[MAX])
{
    pthread_t tids[MAX];

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        if ((errno = pthread_create(&tids[i], NULL, funcproperties, properties[i])) != 0)
            ERROR(C_ERRO_PTHREAD_CREATE, "pthread_create() failed!");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
        printf("\n PID:%lu DAD: %lu TID: %lu", properties[i]->myPid, properties[i]->parentPid ,properties[i]->myTid);
}
```

This is the result I'm getting (I force pid to define. However, if I'm not mistaken, I'm getting random values).

```
     PID:0 DAD: 3076323888 TID: 134519979
     PID:612976384 DAD: 3077911516 TID: 3220212208
     PID:0 DAD: 3076323888 TID: 134519979
     PID:612976384 DAD: 3077911516 TID: 3220212208
     PID:0 DAD: 3076323888 TID: 134519979
     PID:612976384 DAD: 3077911516 TID: 3220212208
     I 9292 did my job now make yourself served
```

PS: I'm also using processes.

Comment: Your use of the term 'typedef' is unusual — misleading, if not downright wrong.  I think you're trying to pass a structure to the function, but the structure has no tag and the type name is specified via a `typedef`.  What you pass is not a `typedef`, then — it is a structure, or a pointer to a structure.

Comment: I'm also deeply suspicious about the pointer to an array passed to the function `createthread()`.  If your calling function has `myProperties mp[MAX];` and initializes that, and then passes `&mp` to `createthread()`, then `properties[1]` in `createthread()` is referencing out of bounds of the array, which may be part of the trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *must* ensure that it is impossible for one thread to access an object while another thread might be modifying it. You have not done this, so the results are unpredictable.

One solution would be to call `pthread_join` on all the threads before looking at the values they are setting.

Comment: I wonder why since, both threads are changing diferents parts of the program?

Comment: One is changing typdef[0]

Comment: While the other is chaning typdef[1]

Comment: Thanks is working, now, still would be awesome, if you could explain why.

Comment: @JoãoMarques When the original thread enters the last `for` loop, it is accessing `typdef[0]`. At that same time, the first thread you created in the first `for` loop might be modifying it. You must ensure that it is not possible for one thread to access an object while another thread might be modifying it.